# What does the upcoming demise of Blog Overflow mean for the Server Fault blog?

Tags: support, blog

The community blogging platform Blog Overflow is going away. However, the [Server Fault blog](http://blog.serverfault.com/) was never a community blog to begin with: it’s The Stack Exchange Sysadmin Blog. On the other hand, it does still exist as a WordPress blog on the Blog Overflow platform, unlike the [Stack Overflow blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/) which was [moved to a new platform](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/07/how-we-built-our-blog/) a while ago (and a new domain name more recently).

So will the Server Fault Blog be frozen into static pages with the rest of Blog Overflow, migrate to Jekell like the Stack Overflow blog, move elsewhere entirely, or be integrated into the Stack Overflow blog?

(Tagging [support](/questions/tagged/support) because I’d like an official answer.)

Comment: I didn't even knew we had a blog o_0.  Good to know, seem great content on it, just seen Mark's article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the SRE Manager at Stack Overflow.

The official plan is: Leave it as-is for now, decide what to do with it in 2017.

The current round of WordPress deprecation is focusing on community blogs, which ServerFault blog is not a part of.

Unofficially: My current thinking is that we will freeze it like we learned how to do with the community blogs. Future posts will either go on the company [engineering blog](http://stackoverflow.blog/engineering/) or to a new site. A new site is a lot more work. Work is bad.

Comment: With one last post saying "future updates can be found at ..."?

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen Absolutely.

Comment: **Work is bad** ? lol, a retirement sentence - *fire all that staff then !*

Comment: The trick is to do as little work as possible with as much impressiveness as possible. Then sit back and drink coffee.

Comment: Perhaps this could use an update?