# URL for the SE for Android application is invalid

Tags: discussion, blog

In the [Edit Profile & Settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) page, under the **Applications** section there is a list of authorized applications are displaying.

In the list of applications, for the Stack Exchange Android app (SE for Android) the URL is mapped as [blog.stackexchange.com](http://blog.stackexchange.com).

Hope previously it was mapped with some valid blog post link, and [due to this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291741) this link was reset to [blog.stackexchange.com](http://blog.stackexchange.com).

In this case, the linked URL is meaningless. For this link shall we update some valid URL link.

> [image: SE for Android link URL]