# Archived Arqade Blog Overflow gets certificate error

Tags: bug, ssl, blog-overflow

http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2012/08/identifying-games-when-you-cant-remember-the-name/ redirects to https://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2012/08/identifying-games-when-you-cant-remember-the-name/

And then I get a certificate error. If I proceed, the page renders fine. Can we fix it so it either has the right certificates or just uses http or whatever the resolution should be so users don't have to go out of their way to tell the browser that they want to visit an "unsafe" site?

We use a link to this blog in one of our custom close reasons on Arqade, so it would really go a long way towards helping new users who have just had their questions closed.

Comment: Shouldn't the blog just be removed, since there should not be site-specific blogs any more?

Comment: It is the same as web archive, we can't really expect it to work well. If we complain about it too much, they'll just remove it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman They should still [have a static page as previously described](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291741/we-will-no-longer-be-hosting-blog-overflow). Think we just need to fix some certificate things since it says that we're missing a valid certificate.

Comment: @GraceNote It seems to use a certificate that was issued to `*.stackexchange.com`.